# cygwin shell in Emacs - output messed up?

Tags: emacs, cygwin

I saw an answer here how to start the cygwin shell. However, the cygwin shell output is messed up.

```
(defun cygwin-shell ()
  "Run cygwin bash in shell mode."
  (interactive)
  (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "C:/cygwin/bin/bash"))
    (call-interactively 'shell)))
(setq  explicit-bash-args '("--login" "-i"))
```

and here is a sample output of the shell

```
]0;~
seth@seth ~
$ cd ~
]0;~
seth@seth ~
$ dir
]0;~
seth@seth ~
```

as one can see, output is screwed up. How do i fix this?

edit: i just noticed that ^[]0 always appears at the end of each command \ otherwise output text works fine. Anyway to get rid of this ending?

Answer (score 4):

alright, i figured this out. in ~/.bashrc, i added

```
export PS1="\e[0;31m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m "
```

this makes prompt red in single line (which is easy on eyes vs the yellow in original cygwin prompt!)

see 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/

In addition, you have to make sure you do not use dos endings. To convert dos endings to unix, type C-x RET f unix and save or place in .emacs file

```
(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'unix)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Emacs 24.2, I had to put the `export PS1=...` line from Seth's answer (2) in ~/.emacs_bash instead of in ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [EmacsW32](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/EmacsW32). With it, your `.emacs` configuration becomes

```
  (setq w32shell-cygwin-bin "c:\\cygwin\\bin")
  (require 'w32shell)
  (w32shell-add-emacs)
  (w32shell-set-shell "cygwin")
```

and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
export PS1="\e[0;32m\u@\h\e[m \e[0;33m\w\e[m\n\$ "
```

If you like to keep the original color and format.